# Why is the Neo4j Bolt Driver inconsistent between shell and IDE?

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I see a strange behavior with the `neo4j-bolt-driver`. When I use `Pycharm` to run my code it works perfectly well and for a single query to `neo4j` I get the below response:

```
type: neo4j.node    # I pulled out the type of the element.
<Node id=3820 labels={'city'} properties={'ID': 'xddy', 'name': 'california'}>
```

Now when I package my code and create an `.egg` out of it, and then use the terminal to run the script for the same input to the same database I get the below response:

```
type: neo4j.node    # I pulled out the type of the element.
(_3820:city {ID: 'xddy', name: 'california'})
```

Now have a look at the difference in the responses, the type is the same just the `keys` to the object are missing.

> And this leads to an `AttributeError`. Worse is I have to manually parse the data into a dict so that I can process it.

---

**Side Effects:**

```
try:
    props = node[admin].properties
    node_chain[list(node[admin].labels)[0]] = props
    address.append(props['name'])
except AttributeError:

    # try to convert (_3820:city {ID: 'xddy', name: 'california'})
    # to {'ID': 'xddy', 'name': 'california'}
    # and add it to an existing dict with the key `city`

    string_rep = str(node[admin])
    splitted = string_rep.split('{')
    label = splitted[0].split(':')[-1].strip()
    payload_string = "{ " + splitted[1][:-1]
    clean = payload_string.replace("'", " ").replace(":", "':'").replace(",", "','")\
        .replace("{", "{'").replace("}", "'}")
    temp_dict = ast.literal_eval(clean)
    payload_dict = {k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in temp_dict.items()}
    address.append(payload_dict['name'])
    node_chain[label] = payload_dict
```

---

I am looking for two answers:

- Is there an issue in the bolt driver or is it just my code when run from an `egg`
- Is there a better way to parse the invalid content into a dict?

Comment: Are you running in the same environment between PyCharm and your shell? I would suspect what has happened here is that they are not the same environment and that each one has a different version of the `neo4j-driver` module. Are you using a virtual environment for this? In PyCharm, under Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter, is the interpreter set to the same executable path as `whereis python` (or `python2` or `python3` if that is what you use) returns when executed in your shell? Or, if you use a virtualenv, is the PyCharm project interpreter set to that?

Comment: @RebeccaNelson They both are using the same virtual env. Wait have they changed the response from the `Bolt` query in a few versions? if so, which one is the latest (hopefully the one with proper labels and properties)?

Comment: Well... well I'm stumped. They should be the same version then... Okay, I realize I'm asking you to "prove" what you're saying, and I apologize, but for completeness' sake, what is the path that the project interpreter is set to, and what is the exact command(s) you use to activate the virtualenv and execute from shell?

Comment: @RebeccaNelson in `Pycharm` the interpreter path is `X:\Projects\Python\HybridCart\venv\Scripts\Python` while on the terminal when I run it I `cd X:\Projects\Python\HybridCart\venv\Scripts\` and then type in `activate` and then type in `python` to start the `console` and then just do a import statement followed by a `process_order()` function call.

Comment: The API for `neo4j-driver` has indeed changed very recently. I actually had a new deploy of a project in which `neo4j-driver` was not pinned to a specific version, and it completely broke my app when updating the module; even between two minor version numbers if I recall. For reference, this was about 2 weeks ago, and I had originally set the version about 2 months ago.

Comment: @RebeccaNelson can you please point out, out of the two response structures I have shown in the question, which one is the latest one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168979/discussion-between-rebecca-nelson-and-iam-carrot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have a discrepancy in your execution environments.**

Even though you are using the same virtual environment for both shell execution and the PyCharm project interpreter, when executing an .egg the execution environment may be modified to pull in fresh copies of all the libraries, which are not necessarily installed to the "global" module path ("global" here meaning either system-wide when not using a virtualenv, or in the python modules of the virtualenv).

Your PyCharm notes that it is using version `1.5.3` of the `neo4j-driver` module, but the version that pip pulled in to your .egg executation environment is `1.6.0a`, the latest at the time of dependency resolution. And so, when executing it from the shell, you are using a different version of `neo4j-driver`.

That in and of itself wouldn't be so bad, but...

**There are currently breaking changes between 1.5.3 and 1.6.0 of neo4j-driver.**

1.6.0 changed the paths of some of the modules, so specific imports might break. It seems it also changed the format of some of its data objects, as you've seen in your example.

At first it would seem that this is just a consequence of using an unstable tag of the version, but it's very possible that these changes might be here to stay, as it is a new version.

**To ensure the same version is installed by pip/setuptools, pin the version number.**

1.6.0 drastically changed the API in some respects. Since you were developing against 1.5.3, you will have to either change your API to handle both versions (and possibly risk it breaking again when future updates are released), or pin it to a particular version.

To pin it, wipe out any existing versions of `neo4j-driver` by removing all binaries from your build dir, uninstall it with pip, then update your `setup.py` or other dependency management tool to point to the specific version you are developing with.

For `setup.py`, add `==1.5.3` to the end of the name of the library in the `install_requires`, `tests_require` or other relevant sections.